# ヘッダファイル(.h)が見つからず

Tags: swift, xcode

SwiftでObjective-Cのクラスを読み込むために
SocketRocket-Bridge-Header.hというファイルを作成し、その中にimportの記載しました。

```
#ifndef RemoteControl_SocketRocket_Bridge_Header_h
#define RemoteControl_SocketRocket_Bridge_Header_h
#import "SRWebSocket.h"
#endif
```

[Build Settings]の[Objective-C Bridging Header]に
`$(SRCROOT)/$(PRODUCT)/RemoteControl/SocketRocket-Bridge-Header.h`
と設定していますが、以下のエラーが発生します。
`/Users/sagyo/Copy/iPhoneアプリ/RemoteControl/RemoteControl/SocketRocket-Bridge-Header.h:12:9: 'SRWebSocket.h' file not found`

SRWebSocket.hのフルパスは
`/Users/sagyo/Copy/iPhoneアプリ/RemoteControl/RemoteControl/SocketRocket-BrHeader.h`
です。

XCodeを再起動しもエラーは直りません。

Always Search User Pathsも有効(YES)にしました。でもエラーが出ます。

対処方法をご存知の方はご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

日本語のパス名が嫌な予感がします。
アプリの名称をローマ字にして（いろいろなパスが影響すると思うので、できれば一旦ミニマムで新規アプリを作成して）試してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

試しにフルパスで#importしてみては？